# Folded/hierarchic logging system?

Tags: logging

Does a logging system (for whatever language)  enables to add open/close tags (for instance when we enter and exit a method) and to view these logs by showing the hierarchy of tags -> you can fold/unfold a tag to see the traces inside.

It can be done manually:  I can log information in a xml format and use an xml browser. but a dedicated system would work much better in my opinion.

The usual log systems with categories does not fullfill my needs, I want to see the structure of the traces, jump quickly to the ith iteration of a loop,...

Does such a solution exist ?

I hope you understand my question,
Thanks in advance.